# R : bond return dispersion (0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,0.9,0.95,0.99,0.995)

Tags: r, quantile, percentile

I have a bond return panel data and would like to come up with the dispersion of returns.

This is how my dataset looks like

```
           ID        date        return  
            A         5/15        0.2
            A         6/15        0.1  
            ...        ...        ... 
            B         5/15        0.5
            B         6/15        0.7 
            ...        ...        ...  
            C         5/15        0.3
            C         6/15        0.7  
            ...        ...        ...
```

and the result I want is this

```
                             Percentiles
            .005     .01    .05    .10    .50    .90    .95    .99    .995  
    return   -0.3%   -0.1%   0%    0.2%   0.4%   0.7%   0.9%  1.3%    1.4%
```

Basically, I want to get the return dispersion. I will first compute the percentile each month and average each of the percentile groups and make the table above.

I have tried doing

```
      DT <- DT %>%
      group_by(date) %>%
      mutate(percentile = quantile(return,c(.005,.01,.05,.10,.50,.90,.95,.99,.995)))
```

But returns are not ranked according to the percentiles but rather it showed some numbers that are in sequence that I don't understand.

I want to put the returns each month into those 10 bins based on the percentage that I have set.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 dat <-quantile(c(.005,.01,.05,.10,.50,.90,.95,.99,.995))

 dat

   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
 0.005 0.050 0.500 0.950 0.995
```

You can adjust output via probs command, such as

```
 dat.1 <-quantile(c(.005,.01,.05,.10,.50,.90,.95,.99,.995),probs=seq(0,1,0.1))

 dat.1

   0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%  100% 
0.005 0.009 0.034 0.070 0.180 0.500 0.820 0.930 0.966 0.991 0.995
```